# TCP connection broken detection (If intermediate link goes down)?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

Assuming the implementation in C. 
If the intermediate link goes down, through which the TCP connection was sending the data. Will the sockets at both ends become unusable to send and receive data immediately?

If the link comes up after 5-6 secs, Can the same sockets be used to send and receive the packets?

Answer (score 2):

The TCP/IP protocol suite was designed to work over unreliable links. If the connection comes back after a few seconds the applications only notice a drop in throughput.

Comment: Just curious- IF the intermediate link does not comes up, after what time the end sockets get a RST or some such error on read()/write()?

Comment: Just found another useful and related SO post , which does answer my query - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17326918/send-function-behavior-when-link-goes-down-in-a-tcp-connection

Comment: TCP will try to retransmit packets every few seconds. If no reply is received it may keep doing that for hours, though I don't have any reference to back that up. Receiving an RST would mean the link came back up.