# send() function behavior when link goes down in a TCP connection

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, send

Following is the scenario:

A <-------------------------> B

I am using non-blocking Sockets on both A and B (linux based machines). 
A and B have a TCP connection and suddenly the link connecting them goes down (The link may not be direct link).
Now after the link is down, when send() function is called on side A to send some data to B , It returns successfully (i.e it returns the number of bytes that are to be sent).

What is the reason for this behavior, when we know the remote side will not be able to receive  this data, when the link is down?

Comment: Are you sure you're using TCP?  Also, what do you mean the link goes down?  Do you close the socket on B, or do you unplug it?

Comment: I am not closing the socket. Unplugging can better describe the scenario

Comment: The semantics of the scenario are important in this case I presume.  If computer B is still on the network, and you send it packets, its network card is probably sending back an ack even though the packet isn't getting sent up to the application layer.  If it is on the network, its probably why you're receiving a success return value.

Comment: Actually A and B are routers in my case. I am issuing a port shut command at A, which should stop all outgoing packets from A.

Comment: So you're sending from A to B, and you shutdown A and A still sends all the packets?  Maybe it waits till the buffer is empty to shutdown/it flushes the out buffer.

Comment: What operating system? Does the "port shut" command do something to the TCP states of connections using that port, or does the internal IP layer try to find a different port?

Comment: @Magn3s1um Your comments make no sense. Network cards don't send ACKs, TCP stacks do, and send() doesn't wait for an ACK before returning. 'Port shut' doesn't know anything about buffers. You seem to be just guessing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is normal and expected behaviour.

> when we know the remote side will not be able to receive this data

Well, maybe *you* know, because you are the one you pulled the cable and you aren't about to plug it back in again, but the computer (or, in particular, the TCP stack) doesn't know.

The first reason why it doesn't know the data won't make it is that by the time the `send()` call completes, the data haven't gone on the wire yet: they've only been queued in a buffer.

The second reason why it doesn't know the data won't make it is that it can't (at least at first) tell the difference between a link that has simply dropped a packet and the packet may get through when it tries to retransmit it, versus a cable that has been well and truly cut. Even for a cable cut, TCP will keep retransmitting for a while, hoping that either (1) the link comes back, or (2) routers will converge on another network path that works.

Even if you could know instantly when a link is down (although you can in some very specific cases, you can't in general, you must wait for a timeout to figure this out), you wouldn't want TCP to instantly break connections every time it happened: it would be way too fragile if TCP connections broke every time a packet was lost in the network.

Comment: Does send() call returns success as soon as the data is queued in the TCP send buffer?

Comment: Suppose I dont plug in the wire, does this mean that TCP will always keep on retransmitting the packet(s) if does not receive the ack? When will it actually detect the link failure?

Comment: Yes, `send()` returns success as soon as the data have been accepted by the kernel. If you never replug the wire, TCP will eventually time out (after several minutes, generally) and further operations on the socket will return a timeout error.

Comment: What is the default retransmission timeout in TCP? How frequently will it try to retransmit a lost packet

Comment: Is there any reference describing this behavior?